# using GetFieldValueAsync with type from GetFieldType

Tags: c#, async-await, dbdatareader

I have a generic reader and I want to transform it from sync to async.

The original code is

```
while (DR.Read())
{
    count++;
    Field[] fields = new Field[DR.FieldCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < DR.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        Field field = new Field();
        field.RowCount = count;
        field.FieldCount = i;
        field.Name = DR.GetName(i);
        field.DataType = DR.GetDataTypeName(i);
        // decimal overflow workaround 
        field.ObjValue =
            field.DataType == "Decimal"?
            DR.GetDouble(i) :
            DR.GetValue(i);
        fields[i] = field;
    }
    yield return fields;
}
```

and it is ok.
What I have tried to do is

```
List<Field[]> ret = new List<Field[]>();
while (await DR.ReadAsync())
{
    count++;
    Field[] fields = new Field[DR.FieldCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < DR.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        Field field = new Field();
        field.RowCount = count;
        field.FieldCount = i;
        field.Name = DR.GetName(i);
        field.DataType = DR.GetDataTypeName(i);
        // decimal overflow workaround 
        field.ObjValue =
            field.DataType == "Decimal" ?
            ((object)await DR.GetFieldValueAsync<double>(i)) :
            ((object)await DR.GetFieldValueAsync(i));
        fields[i] = field;
    }
    ret.Add(fields);
}
```

which is not working because of error CS0411

> The type arguments for method '`GetFieldValueAsync`' cannot be
> inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I have also tried to specify the type from  `Type t = DR.GetFieldType(i)` but I can't do `await DR.GetFieldValueAsync<t>(i)` either.

Am I out of luck here?

Should I revert to the following blocking code inside my async method?

```
// decimal overflow workaround 
field.ObjValue =
    field.DataType == "Decimal" ?
    DR.GetDouble(i) :
    DR.GetValue(i);
```

Is there a theoretical reason why there is no `DR.GetValueAsync(i)` returning an object like the sync counterpart??

**Minor note, out of topic**

In case someone insists to know why I'm writing a different code for decimal, [this is the issue](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/75).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asssume you're talking about the [`DbDataReader` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader).

From the documentation:

> Reads a forward-only stream of rows from a data source.

Once the row is read by either [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.reada) or [ReadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.readasync), the values for that row will all be in memory, which doesn't require any I/O and, thus, doesn't need to be asynchronous.

**Update:**

Turns out, there's a [`GetFieldValueAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getfieldvalueasync) in the [`DbDataReader` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader), but not a `GetValueAsync` method.

Comment: there is a SequentialAccess in the [CommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandbehavior?view=netcore-3.1) for which the GetFieldValueAsync would make sense, so why not an hypothetical GetValueAsync... but yeah I tend to agree to your answer which I would likely accept

Comment: Turns out, there's a GetFieldValueAsync method in the DbDataReader Class, but not a GetValueAsync method.